# get specfic day of week from the previous week via sas macro

Tags: date, macros, sas, dayofweek, sas-macro

Does any one know how to create macro variable with sas macro process to get specific day of week ?

I would like to get Wednesday date of the previous week every time I run the sas macro.

For example :

Today : Tuesday Oct 18,2011--> if I run the macro today I would like to get : 
        "Wednesday Oct 12, 2011"

and If I run the macro on Monday , I still want to get the "Wednesday Oct 12, 2011"

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a macro to return the date of the most recent Wednesday. (Also, if you want the date just stored in a macro var...remove the "&weekday;" statement.)

```
%Macro Get_Weekday(date);

 %Let weekday=%sysfunc(putn(
                 %sysfunc(intnx(week.4,&date,0,beginning)),weekdate.));
 &weekday;

%Mend Get_Weekday;

%Put Today is %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(today()),weekdate.)) 
  and the most recent Wednesday is %Get_Weekday(%sysfunc(today()));
%Put If Today was %sysfunc(putn(%eval(%sysfunc(today())-1),weekdate.)) 
  then the most recent Wednesday would be 
   %Get_Weekday(%eval(%sysfunc(today())-1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with `intnx`. Here's an example (not a macro, but it gives you the idea):

First, generate some data:

```
data dates;
 do d=0 to 13;
  date = '15oct2011'd + d;
  output;
 end;
 format date date8.;
run;
```

This will give you the most-recent Wednesday. Note that 'week.4' is the instruction for weeks starting on Wednesday.

```
data dates;
 set dates;
 wed=intnx('week.4',date,0,'beginning');
 format wed date8.;
run;
```

The variable `wed` now contains the date of the most recent Wednesday.

Answer (score 2):

i interpreted your question as "How to have SAS return the date for the Wednesday of **last week** regardless of the current day of week?"

if that's your desired outcome, then two `intnx` calls are needed: one call to move back to Sunday of last week (`lastwk=intnx('week', today, -1);`) and then a second call to move ahead to Wednesday of last week (`lastwed=intnx('week.4', lastwk , 1);`).

a simpler way might be to go back to the beginning of last week and simply add 3 to the result, but that code appears more like a hack than an intentional offset.

## code

```
data _null_;
    do i = -10 to 10;
        today="&SYSDATE9"d + i;
        lastwk=intnx('week', today, -1);
        lastwed=intnx('week.4', lastwk , 1);
        put today weekdate. '-->' lastwed weekdate.-l;
    end;
run;
```

## log

```
      Sunday, October 9, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
     Monday, October 10, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
    Tuesday, October 11, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
  Wednesday, October 12, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
   Thursday, October 13, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
     Friday, October 14, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
   Saturday, October 15, 2011-->Wednesday, October 5, 2011
     Sunday, October 16, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
     Monday, October 17, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
    Tuesday, October 18, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
  Wednesday, October 19, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
   Thursday, October 20, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
     Friday, October 21, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
   Saturday, October 22, 2011-->Wednesday, October 12, 2011
     Sunday, October 23, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
     Monday, October 24, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
    Tuesday, October 25, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
  Wednesday, October 26, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
   Thursday, October 27, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
     Friday, October 28, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
   Saturday, October 29, 2011-->Wednesday, October 19, 2011
```

Comment: Just as info, if Wednesday is the desired day of the week you can always find last Wednesday by using the following:  lastwed=intnx('week', today, -1, 'm');